# Is overriding of a function possible in the same class?

Tags: c#, oop, overriding

it's an objective question type, but Is overriding of a function possible in the same class? in general, and in C# to be exact. If it is possible how and when can it be used?

Comment: Why you want that first of all??

Comment: Overriding a method inside the same class would just be the same as changing the method.

Comment: is it a partial class defined in multiple places?

Comment: I don't think there is a way, or a need to do such thing, however, if you want to separate the method signature from the implementation, there are partial methods for that, but I don't suggest to use this unless it is absolutely necessary.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30101/Introduction-to-Partial-Methods

Comment: I don't have an example case to share, I just crossed the concept throw a job Interview. and to be honest it made me wonder. for that reason I asked if there's, how can it be used

Comment: More than likely it was about overloading not overriding.

Comment: Do you / they mean overriding from base classes or overloading a method within the same class?

Comment: I'm aware of "changing the method" or "overloading", I'm sure this isn't what they meant

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: There are cases where it would be helpful to override a base member and shadow it with a new member in the same class.  E.g. If `CarFactory` has a virtual member `Car Build()`, it could be helpful for `FordFactory` to override that but also shadow it with `Ford Build()`.  Such shadowing could also be useful in cases where a base class wants to process calls to a base-class virtual method before derived classes do so.  In practice, both situations generally require having non-virtual or sealed methods chain to protected members with different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the C# Language Specification [§10.6.4 Override methods](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/17.5.4.htm)

> The method overridden by an override declaration is known as the
>   overridden base method. For an override method M declared in a class
>   C, the overridden base method is determined by examining each base
>   class type of C, starting with the direct base class type of C and
>   continuing with each successive direct base class type, until in a
>   given base class type at least one accessible method is located which
>   has the same signature as M after substitution of type arguments. For
>   the purposes of locating the overridden base method, a method is
>   considered accessible if it is public, if it is protected, if it is
>   protected internal, or if it is internal and declared in the same
>   program as C.
>
> A compile-time error occurs unless all of the following are true for
>   an override declaration:
>
> - An overridden base method can be located as described above.
> - There is exactly one such overridden base method. This restriction has effect only if the base class type is a constructed type where the
>     substitution of type arguments makes the signature of two methods the
>     same.
> - The overridden base method is a virtual, abstract, or override method. In other words, the overridden base method cannot be static or
>     non-virtual.
> - The overridden base method is not a sealed method.
> - The override method and the overridden base method have the same return type.
> - The override declaration and the overridden base method have the same declared accessibility. In other words, an override declaration
>     cannot change the accessibility of the virtual method. However, if the
>     overridden base method is protected internal and it is declared in a
>     different assembly than the assembly containing the override method
>     then the override method’s declared accessibility must be protected.
> - The override declaration does not specify type-parameter-constraints-clauses. Instead the constraints are
>     inherited from the overridden base method. Note that constraints that
>     are type parameters in the overridden method may be replaced by type
>     arguments in the inherited constraint. This can lead to constraints
>     that are not legal when explicitly specified, such as value types or
>     sealed types.

So no it is not possible, the override modifier is used to extend the base class method not for hiding method definitions in the current class.

Maybe it is possible that your interviewer got confused by method selection after a method has been overridden, for example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39.aspx#sectionToggle0).

Answer (score 4):

Well you can't. Per definition (from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)): The override modifier is required to extend or modify the abstract or virtual implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or event.

You can't inherit of the class itself ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kty4k630%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) so you can't override in the same class.

One thing that is close to overriding and that you can do is method overloading.

```
public class A
{
    void methodA()
    {
        //something here
    }

    void methodA(int i)
    {
        //something else here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically this is not possible using standart approach. But practically you can do it with changing delegates (more close to own methods). But this is not far away from changing behavior via objects, helpers (providing services by interface contacts) - which is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test1
{
    public virtual void Test2() {

    }

    public override void Test2() {

    }
}
```

gives you a compilation error. So, no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it. 
The class itself will not give the compiler a reason to show an error or even a warning but when you call the function the compiler shows:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'method1' and 'method2'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't be overridden. However, I do see how it can be useful. For example, if one wanted to manually override machine-generated code.